# While sending Spinner Value to php file first time only its working

Tags: android, android-spinner, android-json

I want to pass the Spinner value to php and get some result and display into my TextView. when i use Toast to display the Selected value its working perfect.but while pass the value to the php file i am struck. I tried some ways. can some to fix my problem.

java file:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getSupportActionBar().hide(); //<< this for hide title bar
        setContentView(R.layout.sales_order);

    fg.setOnItemSelectedListener(
                    new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                        public void onItemSelected(
                                AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                            if(goods_name1.getSelectedItem() !=null && goods_name1.getSelectedItem() !=""){
                                // WebServer Request URL
                                String serverURL = "http://IP/fs/getProductOneStock.php";
                                // Use AsyncTask execute Method To Prevent ANR Problem
                                new LongOperation().execute(serverURL);
                            }
                        }

                        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
                            showToast("Spinner1: unselected");
                        }
                    });
}

// Class with extends AsyncTask class
    private class LongOperation  extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {

        // Required initialization
        private final HttpClient Client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        private String Content;
        private String Error = null;
        private ProgressDialog Dialog = new ProgressDialog(Sales_Order.this);
        String data ="";
        int sizeData = 0;
        TextView pro_stock1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv_stock1);
        Spinner fgStock = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner1);

        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // NOTE: You can call UI Element here.
            //Start Progress Dialog (Message)

            Dialog.setMessage("Please wait..");
            Dialog.show();

            try{
                // Set Request parameter
                data +="&" + URLEncoder.encode("data", "UTF-8") + "="+fgStock.getSelectedItem();

            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        // Call after onPreExecute method
        protected Void doInBackground(String... urls) {
            /************ Make Post Call To Web Server ***********/
            BufferedReader reader=null;
            // Send data
            try
            {
                // Defined URL  where to send data
                URL url = new URL(urls[0]);
                // Send POST data request
                URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
                conn.setDoOutput(true);
                OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
                wr.write(data);
                wr.flush();
                // Get the server response
                reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                String line = null;
                // Read Server Response
                while((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
                {
                    // Append server response in string
                    sb.append(line + "");
                }
                // Append Server Response To Content String
                Content = sb.toString();
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                Error = ex.getMessage();
            }
            finally
            {
                try
                {
                    reader.close();
                }
                catch(Exception ex) {}
            }
            return null;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Void unused) {
            // NOTE: You can call UI Element here.

            // Close progress dialog
            Dialog.dismiss();

            if (Error != null) {

                pro_stock1.setText("Output : "+Error);

            } else {

                // Show Response Json On Screen (activity)
                pro_stock1.setText( Content );

                /****************** Start Parse Response JSON Data *************/

                String OutputData = "";
                JSONObject jsonResponse;

                try {

                    /****** Creates a new JSONObject with name/value mappings from the JSON string. ********/
                    jsonResponse = new JSONObject(Content);

                    /***** Returns the value mapped by name if it exists and is a JSONArray. ***/
                    /*******  Returns null otherwise.  *******/
                    JSONArray jsonMainNode = jsonResponse.optJSONArray("Finish_goods_mas");

                    /*********** Process each JSON Node ************/

                    int lengthJsonArr = jsonMainNode.length();

                    for(int i=0; i < lengthJsonArr; i++)
                    {
                        /****** Get Object for each JSON node.***********/
                        JSONObject jsonChildNode = jsonMainNode.getJSONObject(i);

                        /******* Fetch node values **********/
                        String Stock1 = jsonChildNode.optString("Finish_goods_mas").toString();
                        OutputData += Stock1;


                    }
                    /****************** End Parse Response JSON Data *************/

                    //Show Parsed Output on screen (activity)
                    //jsonParsed.setText( OutputData );

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

my php  file

```
    <?php
require "db_config.php";
$Goods_name=$_POST['Goods_name'];
$sql = "select goods_min_level from Finish_goods_mas where Goods_name='".$Goods_name."'";
$stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql );
if( $stmt === false) {
    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true) );
}

while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
      //echo $row['cus_id']."<br />";
      $json['Finish_goods_mas'][]=$row;
}

sqlsrv_free_stmt( $stmt);

echo json_encode($json);
?>
```

after make changes of `doInBackground` and `onPreExecute()` the Spinner value not pass to php file also i cannot get back result from php

Comment: Due to `ShowProStock ` method because updating UI elements from `doInBackground `

Comment: ShowProStock () method is use to get the JSON from server

Comment: this is not aswer but give you suggestion for improving code use  HttpUrlConnection instead of httpclient and httppost because it's depricated.

Comment: and perform UI operation in preExecute and postExecute method.

Comment: okay @ArpitPatel i will try

Comment: I update my question @ρяσѕρєяK